# Identity 2 or 1 in ASP MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Can't seem to find if MVC 5, which I just installed on my machine, uses Identity 1 or 2? I want to create a 2 factor authentication for my site and it seems like its available in Identity 2 and not 1 accordign to documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Neither.  Identity is not tied to the MVC version, although the version installed with MVC5 is 1, you can just upgrade to Identity 2 via Nuget.  While you're at it, upgrade to the latest MVC as well.

Comment: isn't the latest MVC 5?

Comment: What I would really like to know is if two factor authentication (2FA) is available in MVC 5 with Identity 2? Is it prime time yet or still being worked on? If it's not really a prod release I can wait and leave it out for now!

Comment: @user1186050 - No, the latest stable release is MVC 5.1.2, with 5.2 in the rc stage.  Identity is currently at 2.0.1.  Here's an article that describes adding 2 factor auth to identity 2 http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AddingTwoFactorAuthenticationToAnASPNETApplication.aspx